# Convert String to array "{"hitt":"","test":"1"}"

Tags: php, string

I get this string "{"hitt":"","test":"1"}" and i want to convert it into array like
['hitt] = '',
['test'] = 1
kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{"hitt":"","test":"1"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true)    //true to convert to array
var_dump($array)
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    ["hitt"] => string("")
    ["test"] => string("1")
}
```

Comment: @bilalwaheedch upvote and accept if it helped please

Comment: `$json = "{"hitt":"","test":"1"}";` from your example will cause a syntax error.